# Return multiple videos to poster photo

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I have got a website with over 20 videos and use video.js plugin to play them. Recently I have come to a problem - I want each video to be returned back to it's poster photo after it's finished.

I've got this code:

```js
<script>
    var video = videojs('#myvideo');
    video.on('ended', function() {
        video.trigger('loadstart');
        video.posterImage.show();
    });
</script>
```

Everything is ok until I put there more than one video, because this code refers to just one of them with id="myvideo". Is there a way to overwrite this code to be more general or do i have to use for loop and make a function like this for each video on my website?

Thanks for any replies

Comment: you can use a class on the videojs and then inside the callback function you do this.trigger('loadstart'); and this.posterImage.show()

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler in css

```
.video-js.vjs-ended .vjs-poster {
  display: block;
}
```